# Sharing problem for Home Folders

Tags: permissions, shared-folders

I installed the latest 23.10 Ubuntu yesterday, after a hard drive problem. Now, I can't share folders from this location (Downloads) since the new Properties, no longer have the three tabs at the top of the window.

Last release looks like this

[image: Screenshot of folder properties - Local Network Share tab]

Comment: prob. a typo and 23.10 was meant.   Regarding the title:you do not share /home/ directories. You create a mount point and share that using a "group" you add all users to.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable sharing from the terminal using `sudo net usershare add your_share_name ~/Downloads "Your Share Description" everyone:read`